# ¿Cuándo ha finalizado un proceso en linux?

Tags: linux

Ayer lancé un proceso y quisiera ver a qué hora ha finalizado. En los logs del sistema no he visto nada. ¿Con qué comando se podría hacer? (tengo el pid).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dependerá del proceso y dónde escribe sus logs. ¿De qué proceso estamos hablando?. Para otra vez, te puedes hacer un script que primero escriba en un fichero la hora actual (así tienes la hora inicial), luego llame a tu proceso y finalmente escriba en el mismo fichero o en otro la hora actual (así tienes la hora de finalización). Algo así:

```
#!/bin/bash
LOG=/home/david/log.txt
echo "Hora inicio: $(date)" >> $LOG 
miproceso
echo "Hora fin: $(date)" >> $LOG
```

Answer (score 0):

En el caso de una plataforma como LINUX CentOS 7.8, sirve el comando `systemctl status <process_name>`, p.e. como se muestra a continuacion con el proceso del "firewall" que viene con esta versión del OS:

```
[root@srvlabwasdb01 ~]# systemctl status firewalld
● firewalld.service - firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Mon 2022-07-18 09:42:34 -04; 1 months 19 days ago
     Docs: man:firewalld(1)
 Main PID: 958 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jul 18 09:35:13 srvlabwasdb01.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com systemd[1]: Starting firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon...
Jul 18 09:35:14 srvlabwasdb01.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com systemd[1]: Started firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon.
Jul 18 09:35:14 srvlabwasdb01.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com firewalld[958]: WARNING: AllowZoneDrifting is enabled. This is considered an insecure configuration op...it now.
Jul 18 09:42:33 srvlabwasdb01.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com systemd[1]: Stopping firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon...
Jul 18 09:42:34 srvlabwasdb01.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com systemd[1]: Stopped firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
[root@srvlabwasdb01 ~]#
```

Nótese en las primeras líneas como se indica, en el caso de un proceso detenido, la fecha de ultima ejecución y el tiempo transcurrido. Aquí pego nuevamente la línea informativa:

> "Active: inactive (dead) since Mon 2022-07-18 09:42:34 -04; 1 months 19 days ago"